# Increase size-limit of messages written to /dev/kmsg

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, dmesg

I have a custom initramfs whose logging output I wish to redirect to `/dev/kmsg`. The Kernel I am using is `5.10.52`

However, I realized that I cannot write more than `992 bytes` to `/dev/kmsg` at once. Is this size limit configurable via one of the Kernel Configs? Also why is the limit `992` specifically? What I observed is that this limit is `32 bytes` shorter than `1024`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is determined by `LOG_LINE_MAX` in `kernel/printk/printk.c`.

In 5.10.52, that’s defined as [1024 - `PREFIX_MAX`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.52/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L413); the latter is set aside for the log prefix, which is 32 bytes by default, 48 bytes if [`CONFIG_PRINTK_CALLER`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.52/source/lib/Kconfig.debug#L21) is enabled. To increase the limit, replace 1024 with whatever value you deem appropriate.

[Since 5.13](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=cf5b0208fda4602d0ef383a86e942fb3dcb8852b), [`LOG_LINE_MAX`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.1/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L396) is based on [`CONSOLE_LOG_MAX`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.1/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L393), so you’d change that instead.

I don’t know what the knock-on effects of increasing the limit would be, if any.

Comment: Got it, Thanks! Although I wish this was given as a Kernel Config whose value could be changed via menuconfig. Thanks for the links. Since I'm using 5.10.52, the variables are different - [LOG_LINE_MAX](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.52/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L413) for 5.10.52.

Comment: Oops, I should have written this for 5.10.52; I’ve fixed that.